# Magento put single product in catalog mode

Tags: magento

i have a Magento shop and want to do the following:
Some of the products should not be available for buying (they should be put in some kind of catalog mode).
How could this be achieved in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some custom attribute for those products. For example:

```
can_sale
```

And on frontend display add to card button depending on this attribute. Like this:

```
if($product->getCanSale() == 1){
    /*Display add to cart button*/
}else{
    /*Dont' display add to cart button*/
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works! =)
I've added it to the global scope and to All Product Types.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works, but is a template solution for something that (in principle) should be solved server-side.

If any of your visitors is savvy enough to construct an add-to-cart URL, they can still add products you hid the cart button for, to their carts. Probably a very minor problem of course, in this case.

There's an extension called Not2Order, don't know if I'm allowed to link it here. That extension takes care of enabling / disabling the ordering of products from the server side, which is a little more robust.